# How do I set a retry policy on an Azure blob storage operation using the Azure.Storage.Blobs assembly?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

Using the latest ([12.3.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs) at the time of writing) [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/) package for the [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs?view=azure-dotnet) assembly, and uploading asynchronously with the `BlobServiceClient` class, I want to set retry options in case of transient failure.

But no [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet) of the `UploadAsync()` method takes any object with retry options:

```
UploadAsync(Stream, BlobHttpHeaders, IDictionary<String,String>, BlobRequestConditions, IProgress<Int64>, Nullable<AccessTier>, StorageTransferOptions, CancellationToken)
```

And although when creating a `BlobServiceClient`, it is possible to set `BlobClientOptions`, and these do inherit a `RetryOptions` field from the abstract base class `ClientOptions`, this field is read only:

```
    // Summary:
    // Gets the client retry options.
    public RetryOptions Retry { get; }
```

How do I set a retry policy on an Azure blob storage operation using the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` assembly?

Comment: This question has been resolved, and I added the API reference link. - [BlobClientOptions Class (Azure.Storage.Blobs) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should specify the retry part when creating the blob client. Here's a sample:

```
    var options = new BlobClientOptions();
    options.Diagnostics.IsLoggingEnabled = false;
    options.Diagnostics.IsTelemetryEnabled = false;
    options.Diagnostics.IsDistributedTracingEnabled = false;
    options.Retry.MaxRetries = 0;

    var client = new BlobClient(blobUri: new Uri(uriString:""), options: options);
```

In addition, it is possible to set the `BlobClientOptions` when creating a `BlobServiceClient`:

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient
(connectionString:storageAccountConnectionString, options: options );
```

You can then use `BlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName:"")` and `BlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName:"")` to build the blob URI in a consistent manner, with options.

Comment: How do I know if a retry actually happened? Is there a way to log information when a retry occurred?

Comment: as far as I could see there's no "flag" for that: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/a42b1b682ac01fe7a5a04be54bf5c1096b3ddb1c/sdk/batch/Microsoft.Azure.Batch/tests/UnitTests/RetryPolicyUnitTests.cs  You can raise a question in the github, probably a better place for this question