# Azure Storage SDK for .NET: How to set RetryPolicy on the new Blob storage library?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

In the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage (the legacy Azure SDK for .NET), we could set the retry policy for a BlobClient to be an IRetryPolicy like so:

```
var blobClient = this.storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();    
blobClient.DefaultRequestOptions.RetryPolicy = TransientFactory.GetStorageRetryPolicy().AsAzureStorageClientRetryPolicy();
```

However, in the new version of the SDK, with BlobClients being directly created without having to go through a CloudStorageAccount, how can we do this?

The furthest I have been able to get using the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet) is to manually set max retries:

```
 var blobClientOptions = new BlobClientOptions();
 blobClientOptions.Retry.MaxRetries = 4;
 var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("connection_string", options: blobClientOptions);
```

Instead of manually setting retry parameters, is it possible set the *RetryPolicy* on a BlobClient or BlobServiceClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage you post is exactly the way we use. We could set the retry policy in two positions.

One is how you post: set the retry policy when creating blob client.

One set the retry policy when creating `BlobServiceClient`:

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient
(connectionString:storageAccountConnectionString, options: blobClientOptions);
```

Follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60533398/13586071).

Comment: Is it possible to set an IRetryPolicy though anywhere in the new SDK?

Comment: It seems not possible.